# Why does this use of boost::none fail to compile with nvcc?

Tags: c++, cuda, option-type, compiler-bug, boost-optional

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
void foo(boost::optional<unsigned> x = boost::none);
```

placed in the file `a.cu`, with the CUDA compiler, using the following command line:

```
nvcc a.cu -c --std=c++11 -I/opt/boost/include
```

but I get a bunch of errors:

```
a.cu:2:53: error: conversion from ‘const boost::none_t(boost::none_t::init_tag (*)())’ to ‘boost::optional<unsigned int>’ is ambiguous
 void foo(boost::optional<unsigned> x = boost::none);
                                                     ^
/opt/boost/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:805:1: note: candidate: boost::optional<T>::optional(boost::optional<T>::rval_reference_type) [with T = unsigned int; boost::optional<T>::rval_reference_type = unsigned int&&] <near match>
     optional ( rval_reference_type val ) : base( boost::forward<T>(val) )
 ^   ~~~~
/opt/boost/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:805:1: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
a.cu:2:53: error: invalid conversion from ‘const boost::none_t (*)(boost::none_t::init_tag (*)())’ to ‘unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]
 void foo(boost::optional<unsigned> x = boost::none);
                                                     ^
/opt/boost/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:800:1: note: candidate: boost::optional<T>::optional(boost::optional<T>::argument_type) [with T = unsigned int; boost::optional<T>::argument_type = const unsigned int&] <near match>
     optional ( argument_type val ) : base(val) {}
 ^   ~~~~
/opt/boost/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:800:1: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
a.cu:2:53: error: invalid conversion from ‘const boost::none_t (*)(boost::none_t::init_tag (*)())’ to ‘unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]
 void foo(boost::optional<unsigned> x = boost::none);
```

Why does this happen, and can I circumvent the problem while still actually using boost::optional in (host-side) code compiled with nvcc?

Additional information:

- The code compiles fine with g++ 6.3.0 (my distribution's compiler).
- This code (or rather, similar code) *used* to compile and work on an earlier Linux distribution I was using, where the compiler was g++ 5.4.x .
- I've tried this with Boost versions 1.65.1 and 1.69.0 .
- I've tried this with CUDA versions 9.2.88 and 10.0.130 .

Comment: "what can I do about it?" 1. file a boost issue  2. file a NVIDIA bug  3. segregate the boost code into a .cpp file, put your CUDA code in a .cu file, and use wrapper functions to tie the functionality together

Comment: @RobertCrovella: See edit. But I will file issues. I'm guessing the problem is with nvcc rather than Boost.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error and was able to get this to work with this modification:

```
    #define BOOST_OPTIONAL_USE_OLD_DEFINITION_OF_NONE
    #include <boost/optional.hpp>
```

This is using CUDA 10.0.130, g++ 7.3.0, and Boost 1.68.0.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to the second question:

You could consider using [Andrzej Krzemieński](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/)'s neat and self-contained [implementation of an `optional`](https://github.com/akrzemi1) instead of `boost::optional`. It works with C++11, which is what you seem to be doing.